# UITableViewの余分な横線を削除する方法

Tags: ios, uitableview

UITableViewで表示するセルの数が少ない場合下記の写真のようにコンテンツが表示されているセルの下にそのセルと同じ幅で横線が等間隔に並びます。

[image: iPhone画面]

この状態は見た目が良くないのでコンテンツがないセルの横線を表示されないようにしたいです。
どなたか良い方法知りませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

いろいろな方法がありますが、おそらく最も簡単なのは、テーブルビューのフッタに高さがゼロのビューを設定することです。

コードで書くと下記のようになります。

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

同様のことをストーリーボードから設定することも可能です。

Comment: 余分な横線が綺麗に無くなりました。回答ありがとうございます。